# Can I suspend Ith, High Arcanist as my commander directly from the command zone?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-commander

When [Ith, High Arcanist](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bIth%2c%20High%20Arcanist%5d) is in command zone, can I use its suspend ability?
Does the suspend activity cost increase the second time or is the additional cost is only applied to casting cost?

Comment: @doppelgreener the link toward the gatherer does not seem to work

Comment: It works for me... could you right-click the link, copy link address, and paste here where it's pointing for you?

Comment: It points to http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bIth%2c%20High%20Arcanist%5d

Comment: Looks like that link's dependent on your language used for Gatherer; I think the linker presumes you're using English.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No, you cannot.**

Suspend means:

> 702.61. Suspend
>
> 702.61a Suspend is a keyword that represents three abilities. **The first is a static ability that functions while the card with suspend is in a player’s hand.** The second and third are triggered abilities that function in the exile zone. “Suspend N—[cost]” means “**If you could begin to cast this card by putting it onto the stack from your hand**, you may pay [cost] and exile it with N time counters on it. This action doesn’t use the stack,” and “At the beginning of your upkeep, if this card is suspended, remove a time counter from it,” and “When the last time counter is removed from this card, if it’s exiled, play it without paying its mana cost if able. If you can’t, it remains exiled. If you cast a creature spell this way, it gains haste until you lose control of the spell or the permanent it becomes.”

You can only use Suspend from your hand. Since the Command zone is a zone different from your hand, you cannot use Suspend.

This is also summarised in the reminder text for Ith's Suspend ability, which can be read on Gatherer.

Comment: Optionally, can a suspended card be countered when it is played?

Comment: @sinsedrix You can counter a suspended spell when it's cast (after the time counters run out) and it's on the stack. Putting it into suspend-exile in the first place doesn't use the stack, so the spell isn't on the stack, so it can't be countered.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use the suspend ability. From the card's Gatherer rulings:

> 7/1/2013: In a Commander game where this card is your commander, you cannot suspend it from the Command zone.

Comment: You attributed that ruling to magiccards.info, but in fact magiccards.info was only reproducing an official ruling found in Ith's gatherer page (it's [the last ruling on the page](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=114903)). I've edited your post to attribute the ruling to the original and authoritative source.